# css property for breaking sentences

Tags: php, html, css

I've a text `"Europcar The Quickest Way From Runway To Road"`.I want to display this like

```
Europcar
The Quickest Way From Runway To Road
```

how to get in this format using CSS without changing the HTML code.

Comment: what do you mean "without changing the code"?  what is "the code"?

Comment: @Xaxxon, he means the source HTML.
@Nakshathra, can you show us your HTML that you cannot change?

Comment: AFAIK, CSS can't. unless you put a `<br />` or `<p></p>` tag dynamically, may be using JS, at the place. Ideally, "Europcar" should be under a separate tag like `h1, h2, div etc` as the format dictates.

Comment: you ask 13 questions for that you get more than 30 answer, none of them are accepted to you!!!?? Please consider some answer to accept.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original string has now html tags like a span or something else, it's not possible with pure CSS. CSS offers only the pseudo selectors `:first-line` and `:first-letter` but not `:first-word` what you need. In other words, you can't select the first word of a text with CSS to insert a line-break `:after` it.

Answer (score 4):

You can’t really in a nice way.

The only way would be to add (e.g. with `:after`) another block element, position it to where you don’t want the text and make the text float around any top-elements.

With nothing to style there CSS is not the right thing. CSS is for styling, the missing newline is missing some markup however.

Answer (score 3):

> What you are looking for is a
>   pseudoclass that doesn't exist. There
>   is :first-letter and :first-line, but
>   no :first-word.

Here is the topic you can check [CSS to increase size of first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Javascript but not width pure CSS. http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/javascript/first-word-selector/