# How to color the first word using CSS

Tags: php, html, css

How can I color the first word using CSS when I have `div` tag for the title?

```
 <div class="head-logo">  <? echo $siteName ?>  </div>
```

CSS

```
.head-logo{
     text-align:center;
     color:#000000; 
     font:normal 22px Tahoma;
     margin: 0px 10px 20px 60px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of the color from #000000 to something else?

Comment: I think you'll need some [additional HTML markup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440572/css-bold-first-word) or [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word) to do this correctly.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible with pure css. You could turn the first into a span tag using javascript and color that spans content.

Comment: You could always poke at the variable with php, and inject a span into it, with a "first-word" class or something

Comment: You kind of have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171094) going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use php explode

```
<div class="head-logo">
    <?
        $title = explode(" ", $siteName, 2);
        echo '<span style="color: #FF0000">'.$title[0].'</span> '.$title[1]);
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd rather like this answer than mine. I didn't know `explode` function accepted a third parameter to specify the number of fragmentations to perform! That's what I like of answering questions in this site. One helps other people, but one learns a lot too, reading other people's answers. Upvote!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it this way:

```
<div class="head-logo">
    <?
    $title = explode(" ", "My title here");
    echo '<span class="firstWord">'.$title[0].'</span>'.substr(implode(" ", $title), strlen($title[0]));
    ?>
</div>

.head-logo{
    text-align:center;
    color:#000000; 
    font:normal 22px Tahoma;
    margin: 0px 10px 20px 60px;
}

.firstWord{color: red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so there are ways to do this with JS, and some tricky CSS workarounds.

Here's why it doesn't work:
There is no "`::first-word`" pseudo class, since in a code language, one 'word' is a pretty half-baked definition. So the way I have always done this is with `<span>...</span>` tags, but I see you are using PHP to echo your website name, so you may be able to do something along the lines of this using the `::first-line` pseudo element, then making the pseudo a block and picking it's length that way:

CSS:

```
display:block;
Width:40-100px; /* just enough for one word, depends on font size */
Overflow:visible; /* so longer words don't get clipped.*/
float:left; /* so it will flow with the paragraph. */
position:relative; /* for typeset adjustments. */
```

[CSS to increase size of first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word)

This is a JS solution, that essentially replaces adds a span class in your tag and lets you change how many letters are there.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('h2').each(function(){
        $(this).html( $(this).text().replace(/(^\w{5})/,'<span>$1</span>'));
    });
});
```

[Style half of a word, sentence, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195663/style-half-of-a-word-sentence-etc)

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3gMK3/

**The fiddle, CSS, and JS is not mine, just something I found while researching**