# Change styling of part of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/5968383/">
        This is a test question ?
    </a>
</noscript>
```

The css class which styles the text "This is a test question" is "pds-question-top". Is it possible to style part of
this text, ie change the colour of "This" to blue ?

Here it is on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/

Comment: You can only style tags and not words. So you'd have to select the word(s) and wrap them inside a tag which you then can style.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word

Comment: The trick here is that it's being rendered within an iFrame. Your link tag `<a>` doesn't seem to make it into the rendering either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a div like this:

```
<div class="pds-question-top"> This is a test question ?</div>
```

you can replace the text with a new text where 'This' is inside a span.

```
var rp = $('.pds-question-top').text().replace('This', '<span style="color:blue;">This</span>');

$('.pds-question-top').html(rp);
```

Is not a nice solution but it should be work.

Answer (score 0):

Although a JavaScript solution would be nice, see Alex' [answer](http://www.google.com), your text in question is within a `noscript` tag, meaning any attempts to resolve this with JavaScript won't work.

Alternatively I would recommend wrapping said text in a `span` element, *manually*, and then styling that with a class, like so:

### Html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/5968383/">
        <span class="highlight">This</span> is a test question ?
    </a>
</noscript>
```

### Css

```
.highlight
{
    color: #0f0;
}
```