# change color css only first 6 character of text

Tags: html, css

I have phrase as `Client Testimonial` and i want to change only the `Client` i have used only `first-letter` but is there any method in css to change color .. no javascript please.

Comment: There is no :first-word pseudo-element in CSS so it's not possible (without, like you dont want, javascript). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word for reference.

Comment: In case you change your mind concerning the use of js: http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/javascript/first-word-selector/

Comment: Thanks!, then i need to use javascript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about using `:before`?

I would change the text from "Client Testimonial" to "Testimonial", and then with CSS apply the `:before` rule:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="word">Testimonial</div>​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
.word {
 color: black;       
}
.word:before {
 color: red;
 content: "Client ";
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LvZt7/

Comment: While this is viable in terms of the way the page visually appears, it is TERRIBLE for accessibility.  Most screen readers skip over CSS generated content (http://cssgallery.info/testing-the-accessibility-of-the-css-generated-content/).

In addition, this violates the concept of separating content/structure from formatting.

Answer (score 10):

As noted by others, there is (unfortunately*) no `:first-word` pseudo-selector available in CSS (even version 3 or 4, so far as I currently know). However, there are two possibilities that exist without JavaScript, though both have their failings.

The first, and easiest, is to simply wrap the first word in a span:

```
<p><span>Client</span> Testimonial</p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And style the span with the highlight:

```
p span {
    color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U9HGa/1/).

While this approach does require adding an extra, in this case, `span` element for styling purposes it is simple to implement, and works reliably cross-browser.

The second is slightly more fragile, though avoids adding the extraneous `span` tag, but requires, instead, that you add an attribute:

```
<p data-highlightword="Client">Client Testimonial</p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

With the following CSS:

```
p[data-highlightword] {
    position: relative;
}

p[data-highlightword]::before {
    content: attr(data-highlightword);
    color: #f90;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U9HGa/).

This approach relies on the addition of a single attribute to a single element, but does require extra CSS and will only work in compliant browsers. Which is almost all of them, now, with only IE 8, or perhaps 9, and below proving problematic.

Comment: what about browser support issues using data-hihglightword or :before? for :before I found at least this http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/ IMHO I would use basic "stuff" for easier solutions which most likely work with higher amount of older browsers :) but definitely interesting styles you shared even for me hehe.

Comment: The browser support issue is the precise reason for the final paragraph in the answer. Perhaps I didn't raise the issue sufficiently, but, honestly, I'm becoming, as time goes on, more and more jaded by the need to support IE. I *will* support IE, and happily, but I've become somewhat inured to the fact of its (previous) complacency as regards standards. Now, IE 10, on the other hand actually excites me...

Comment: ok, thnx for explanation - and there are rarely any developers who gets excited because of IE :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<p><span style="color: #c0ff33;">Client</span> Testimonial</p>
```

so yes, just style it with `<span></span>` its perfect for that kind of situations.

**Edit:**

This edit is not directed for the post author but for someone just learning to use css: based on "best practises" one should consider using separate .css file for setting styles in a manner like:

```
.client {
   color: #c0ff33;
}
```

and using it like:

```
<p><span class="client">Client</span> Testimonial</p>
```

If you want to specify more and be certain that you only use your `span` style inside `<p></p>` you could also introduce it like:

```
p span.client {
   color: #c0ff33;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LvZt7/97/

You could also do it other way around specifying your p class and not span:

```
<p class="client"><span>Client</span> Testimonial</p>
```

and

```
p.client span {
   color: #c0ff33;
}
```

or just specifying all p span html markings to have text inside span with color `#c0ff33`:

```
<p><span>Client</span> Testimonial</p>
```

and

```
p span {
   color: #c0ff33;
}
```

Comment: I cannot add any html element in it.. The values comes from CMS ie Drupal

Comment: Then javascript is the only way of doing it.

Comment: Yea, it wasn't said in the topic hopefully this will come handy to someone other then :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the word in a `span` and style it instead. As Henrik Ammer stated in a comment, there is no `:first-word`.

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend doing something like this:

```
<span class = "redcolor">Client </span> Testimonial
```

CSS:

```
.redcolor
{
    color: red
}
```

That way if you want anything in red, just give it a div/span with that class