# How to change first word color through css

Tags: css

How to change first word color through css like 'Moodle Theme' actually i want to change the color of 'Moodle' in white and 'Theme' in orange, it is possible to make through css.I can't use here  or any other tags.And no javascript please. Please help me..
Thank You Advance...

Comment: `<span>Moodle</span> Theme`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gw9bH/

Comment: Also somewhat related here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440572/css-bold-first-word

Comment: Downvote for lack of research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely You can do it by using any inline element like Span

**HTML***

```
<div>
    '<span class="color-white">Moodle</span> Theme'
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
    color:orange;
    background-color:#DDD;
}
.color-white
{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BLWxe/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some html and css however you have to be specific with the words.

Code:

```
<div style="background-color:black"><span style="color:white">Moodle&nbsp;</span><span style="color:orange">Theme</span></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GceLV/

Answer (score 1):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRNxC/) link

OR

```
<p class="client"><span>Client</span> Testimonial</p>

.client span{
   color: #c0ff33;
}
```

Other Same [Question Here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218448/change-color-css-only-first-6-character-of-text)

Here is other [Tutorial](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/ht/htspancolor.htm)

Comment: I think OP wants first word, not first letter :)