# select first three characters off a stringin css

Tags: css, underline, heading

I have a heading  named "Happy Starting". Now I want to underline only first three characters. For example, "Hap" only instead of entire "Happy".

How can I select first three characters of "Happy" in css?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: R u Using Jquery in ur project?

Answer (score 4):

CSS don't have anything which can help you to style particular or any n characters.

One way to achieve this is put those 3 characters within span and style it using css.

Something like

```css
.word{
    color: green;
}
.word span{
   color: red;
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="word"><span>Hap</span>py Starting</div>
```

Check this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/LfsLpz5g/

Or you can use `<u>` html tag also.

Comment: Lol you didn't realise about the 'u' tag, until looking at my answer. Happy to help! :)

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning it is not currently possible with CSS alone.

Comment: @ShobhitSrivastava Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

Copying the answer from: [change color css only first 6 character of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218448/change-color-css-only-first-6-character-of-text)

---

How about using `:before`?

I would change the text from "Client Testimonial" to "Testimonial", and then with CSS apply the `:before` rule:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="word">Testimonial</div>​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
.word {
 color: black;       
}
.word:before {
 color: red;
 content: "Client ";
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LvZt7/

Answer (score -3):

Use the `span` tag

The HTML `span` tag is used for grouping and applying styles to inline elements.

There is a difference between the span tag and the div tag. The span tag is used with inline elements whilst the div tag is used with block-level content.

```css
span{
  text-decoration:underline;
  }
```

```html
<p><span>Hap</span>py Starring</p>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can just do this:

```
<h1><u>Hap</u>py Starting!</h1>
```

The 'u' tag underlines, only the text inside it.

Answer (score -3):

**A quick method to Solve the problem**

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;" >Hap</span>py Starting
```

**Or**

Specify an id to the span tag, and you can customize it in the css part

```
<span id="someid" >Hap</span>py Starting
```

In css

```
#someid
{
   text-decoration: underline;
  //do whatever you want
}
```