# HTML CSS font colours

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors, web

I am creating a website and in one of my divs I have different sections of texts.

Can someone tell me how I can change the font colour of just one of the words in the div and all the rest of the words be a different colour?

I'm using HTML and CSS on Macromedia dreamweaver.

Thanks...

Comment: For example you can put word with a different color in a <span>.

Comment: you can try this '<span style="color:red">My Custom Text in Red</span>'

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the text in an element and style it accordingly, if you were to do this using inline CSS, you could use e.g.:

```
Some colours include <span style='color:red;'>red</span>, <span style='color:blue;'>blue</span> and <span style='color:yellow;'>yellow</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following code and a word in different colour while others having a different colour.

```
<span style="color:red"> WORD </span>
```

You can specify any colour at the place of red... or any #value for the colour.

Answer (score 1):

in dreamweaver select word and change color with color picker http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WS753df6af718a350a-709dc768133b3b53744-8000.html
alternaty
the alternative is to use the tag  selected word

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap your word with a `<span>` tag and modify its `color` css property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the first "letter" of the paragraph or of the text div, then you can use CSS pseudo selector `:first-letter`.

```
<style>
    div:first-letter{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Although there is a CSS pseudo selector `:first-letter`, for the first word you have to use `<span>` tag and style it.

```
<div>
    <span style="color: red">This</span> is the solution.
</div>
```

You should check this post also:
[CSS to increase size of first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <style>
     span   { color:pink; float:left; }
     span p { color:green; float:left; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
  </style>

  <span> <p> De </p> sign </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it should be used several times, you should create a class:

```
<style type="text/css">
span.redAndUnderlined {color: red; text-decoration: underline}
</style>
```