# First word on one line CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a grid presenting people. Their names with a picture. The name must be displayed on 2 line. First name on the first line and surname on second one.

**I can't change the html** (I would use `<br/>` tag and it would be solved).

I need to find a way (CSS prefered) to achieve this.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/NsRLC/11/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <article>
        <header>
             <h2>
            <a href="#">Veronique Bertis</a>
        </h2>

        </header>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/130" />
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header>
             <h2>
            <a href="#">Delphine Donlec</a>
        </h2>

        </header>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/130" />
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header>
             <h2>
            <a href="#">Marie-France Aroul</a>
        </h2>

        </header>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/130" />
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header>
             <h2>
            <a href="#">Gwen Domis-Achrall</a>
        </h2>

        </header>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/130" />
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header>
             <h2>
            <a href="#">Marie-Laure Le Fren</a>
        </h2>

        </header>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/130" />
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <header>
             <h2>
            <a href="#">Michel Rian</a>
        </h2>

        </header>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/130" />
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap{
    width:670px;
}

article {
    width:33.3%;
    float:left;
}
h2 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family:arial,serif;
    color:#000;
}
```

I have tried to use `word-spacing` width a high value , that solves part of the problem, but Some surnames have 2 words and I therefore have three lines.

I also have looked for a `:first-word` selector but it doesn't exist... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word)

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with css only but I would love to see a solution for it in css if it is possible

Comment: do you want a new line for each name (separated by a space)?

Comment: Yes that's it in fact it means that a the first space should always be a line-break

Comment: yes, but what should happen if there are multiple names (spaces)? - a newline for each - or - only the first?

Comment: Only the first. First names can be two words, but they are seperated by a dash whereas surnames can have two words seperated by a space and that one should not be a line-break

Comment: Don't think you can do this just with css - but for what it's worth - you could replicate the `word-spacing` effect by setting `display: table-caption;` on the h2 a - http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/NsRLC/14/

Comment: You are going to have to use JavaScript.

Comment: I guess so, I wanted to believe it was possible but it seems I'll have to go for JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to modify the HTML dynamically you can do this (using jQuery):

```
    var $splitter = $("#wrap article header h2 a");
$splitter.each(function(i, e){             
 var $e = $(e);
    var name = $e.text().split(" ");
    var firstname = name.splice(0, 1);
    var last = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < name.length; ++i)
        last += name[i] + " ";
    $e.html(firstname + "<br/>" + last);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, for "Marie-laure Le Fren", "Fren" disapears. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/NsRLC/16/

Comment: That is true. But, how can you split a name if you don't know what are the parts of the first nale, and what are the parts of the last name ?

Comment: Well the thing is that only the first space should be a line-break : first names can be two words, but they are seperated by a dash whereas surnames can have two words seperated by a space and that one should not be a line-break

Comment: @chadocat this will work then: http://jsfiddle.net/NsRLC/17/.... assuming the last name will have only 2 words

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using

```
word-spacing:225px;
```

on the `h2 a` selector this way each word takes atleast 225px which is 33.3% of the 670px

Other than that you have to either use Javascript or HTML

Comment: As I said in my question; I went for that solution at the biginning but the problem is that two word surnames are displayed in two lines and I can't have that

Comment: I do, Marie-Laure Le Fren is spaced out on 3 lines

Comment: see "Marie-Laure Le Fren". "Le Fren" is a surname and it should be on one line.

Comment: @chadocat Ahh I see what you mean. the only other way is to modify the  markup or use JS

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var name = $("#wrap article header h2 a").text().split(" ");
$("#wrap article header h2 a").html(name[0] + "<br/>" + name[1]);
```