# CSS to style first and last word differently

Tags: css

I have a situation where I need to affect styling on some text and I only have access to the CSS. I do not have access to any of the underlying code, so I can not wrap the text in spans or anything of the sort.

The text is "Status: In Stock".

Is there any way with CSS alone that I can make 'Status:' one color and 'In Stock' another color? I was hoping I could so something with :first-word/:last-word, but that apparently doesn't exist.

Another thought was if there was some way to say "style the word before ':' one way, and after ':' another way"

Is any of this possible purely with CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS to increase size of first word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word)

Comment: No, it is not possible to style individual words with pure CSS and no additional markup.

Comment: I thought not. Thank you.

Comment: Is the full text "Status: In Stock" in any sort of containing element by itself?