# CSS content bold single word

Tags: css

I have the following CSS which adds some text after an element:

```
header h1:after {
    content:"Bold \A not bold";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

My aim is to make the first word bold and the rest of the text not bold.

I know how to make all the text bold, and I know I can achieve this using HTML, but for my present purposes, I want to try and achieve this using CSS.

No search results on this for google, can it be done??

Comment: No, you can't. You need almost a little piece of javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS to increase size of first word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word)

Comment: Using `:before` and `:after` positioned absolutely might be a solution. In `:before` you could put bolded text, then in `:after` you could put normal text. I don't know exactly, what is expected as a final result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, how's this for a creative solution? Draw the text as an SVG, and use this as the `content` value of the `:after` pseudo-element in the form of a data URI:

```
header h1:after{
    content:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' height='14' width='85'><text style='alignment-baseline:hanging;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;fill:#000;'><tspan style='alignment-baseline:inherit;font-weight:bold;'>Bold</tspan> not bold</text></svg>");
}
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ojx5s0kc/1/

I think this is as close as you'll get to rich text formatting on a single pseudo-element.

**Note:** I tested this on Chrome, but I believe that IE requires you to encode the SVG code as a valid URI (i.e. you need to encode all those brackets, spaces etc.). You could probably use a tool [like this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Answer (score 6):

you might split the sentence in two pseudoelements like so:

```
h1 { font-weight: normal; display: table; }

h1:after {
    content:" Bold";
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1:before {
    content:"not bold";
    display: table-footer-group;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWbQVw

here I used `display: table-footer-group;` for  `:before` pseudoelement in order to place it visually below the `:after` pseudoelement

Comment: that would mean half the text was before the parent div and half after?

Comment: exactly @alex: note that from an accessibility or semantic perspective this solution should not be worst than using a single pseudoelement. if semantic or accessibility matter then this text must be included in the markup

Comment: What if we are making it localization ? In that case non of the mentioned answers will work

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Jared's answer, here are some helpful tags to include within the url:

---

**Start**

```
content:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'><text style='alignment-baseline:hanging;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;fill:#008ef4;'>
```

**New Line**

```
<tspan x='-4' dy='14'> </tspan>
```

This is moving the cursor down 14px, and setting it to absolute -4 px x to account for the space (The space must be there or the tag will not render)

**Bold**

```
<tspan style='alignment-baseline:inherit;font-weight:bold;fill:#5b5b5b;'> Your Text Here </tspan>
```

**Italic**

```
<tspan style='alignment-baseline:inherit;font-style:italic;fill:#5b5b5b;'> Your Text Here </tspan>
```

**End**

```
</text></svg>");
```

---

Here's a Fiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nbzuytr/)

And here is a google sheet I made to convert html into this SVG code: (Keep in mind this only works with `<b>, <i>, <br>` tags)

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U__xjPAagKtJxo4U7os7slgxHYpqvSwBVVW4OU9V1y4/edit?usp=sharing)