# Line breaks don't work in PHP language files

Tags: php, text, line

I have a scrips creating catalogues. It is prepared for localisation and it works. But there are "Hints" by "hover" explaining details. I would need to add line breaks on some points in these "pseudo tooltips". In my case <br>, "r\n\", and other standard line breakers don't work. I have in *en.php*:

```html
<?php
/* English language configuration */
/* Version 2019-12-12 15:26 */
$lang = array (
'catalogue-hint' = 'REQUIRED Blablabla',
'another-hint' = 'OPTIONAL Blablabla',
...
'another_variable' = 'Blablabla');
?>
```

And the lang string is called in *index.php*

```html
<div class="hint">
 <div class="tooltip">
  <span data-title="<?php echo $lang['catalogue-hint']; ?>">
   <img src="./css/images/hint.png" alt="Hint">
  </span>
 </div>    
</div>
<div class="label">
 <?php echo $lang['catalogue-name']; ?><span class="req"></span>
</div>
```

Using <br> results in:

> REQUIRED <br> Blablabla

I want it:

> **REQUIRED**
> Blablabla

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - how to create a newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character)

Comment: You might also find the [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function helpful.

Comment: I have studied the _nl2br_ function. But I have not find a way how to use it in my language files. As above demonstrated, the lang file is actually an array of about 100 strings used within the whole script (forms, output subpages etc.).

Comment: @MartinSereday Don't use it in the language files, have normal newlines there but use it when you want to display in in the context of an HTML template. Also note that the array syntax is wrong in your example (`=` instead of `=>`).

Comment: I don't know what is displaying your tool tips but `\n` only works in double-quotes `"`.

Comment: I have studied this function, but I have not found a way hot to use it in my script. The language files contain only one _$lang_ array with about 100 text strings ued by _echo_ in other scripts.
So the `'catalogue-hint' = 'REQUIRED Blablabla',` called by `<?php echo $lang['catalogue-hint']; ?>` shall result in 
(line 1) **REQUIRED** 
(line 2) Blablabla

Comment: I have uploaded all to my server at [link](https://cmsimple.sk/irw) In the first required label hint I placed the <br>, in the second required label hint "\n". Have a look. In the second label hint the text is cut after "REQUIRED".

Comment: @Jeto: Replacing all `=>` to `=` broke the script entirely (blank screen).

Comment: @MartinSereday It's the opposite, the code you posted has `=`s.

Comment: Is there a way to have at least the word "REQUIRED" shown e.g. red?

Comment: @Jeto: Ooops, wrong written here. Pardon.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about **php**. It is about **html** and **css**

First. Just put a plain line break into the values:

```php
$lang = array (
'catalogue-hint' = "REQUIRED\nBlablabla", // note the doublequotes!!!
// or
'another-hint' = 'OPTIONAL
Blablabla',
```

Next, you need to edit your `css` file (or style block, makes the tooltip) and add to the `.tooltip .... :hover::after` (or whatever how it is in your css) the attribute

```css
    white-space: pre;
```

which will make the tooltip content to accept a preformatted text.

Also, I recommend escaping special symbols (quotes, < > etc) using e.g. `htmlspecialchars`:

```html
        <span data-title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lang['catalogue-hint']);?>">
```

Complete working example (.php):

```php
<html>
 <body>
  <style>
   .tooltip span {
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
   }
   .tooltip span:hover::after {
    content: attr(data-title); 
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%; top: 30%; 
    z-index: 1; 
    background: rgba(255,255,230,0.9);
    width: 120px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333; 
    white-space: pre; /* preformated text! */
   }
  </style>  
<?php
$lang = array (
 'catalogue-hint' => "REQUIRED\nBlablabla", // note the doublequotes!!!
);
?>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <span data-title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lang['catalogue-hint']);?>">
            <img src="./css/images/hint.png" alt="Hint">
        </span>
    </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ AterLux: Thank you extremly much :-) That's it. Any clue how the two words "REQUIRED/OPTIONAL" can be styled (font-weight, color)?

Comment: @MartinSereday I don't think it is possible using the `content` attribute. To print complex text formatting use a hidden element and JavaScript to show it. Or check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265446/css-content-bold-single-word there is an example of how to create SVG content.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But finally I think that it is not worth to make such complicated tricks because of 5-6 words.