# how can I include different styles to two parts of a single text in h4 header in css?

Tags: html, css

In my html code I have this line:

one two

The result is:
[image]

Instead, I would like to make it with a style similar to this:

[image]

so that the first word is big and bold, and the second one is normal - how can I merge two styles in a single `h4` header?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `span` tag. You can read more about them here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_span.asp

```css
h4 span{
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<h4><span>Big</span> Normal</h4>
```