# How to style the submit button first word using jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need to style the first/last word in submit button using jQuery or CSS.

Code below:

```css
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {
font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
   <div id="btnDiv" class="btnDiv"> <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT REQUEST" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"></div>
```

I want to change the first-word font weight to light, Is this possible?

Please note: I can't change my HTML code. This is a WordPress site. The Submit button coming from a plugin called 'Contact Form 7'.

Comment: Not possible with CSS alone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word You'll have to change the HTML

Comment: Oops, I can't change the HTML, It's coming from a plugin called contact form 7. This is a WordPress Site :(

Comment: You say you can use jQuery (or Javascript), and if you can use Javascript, you *can* change the HTML

Comment: Is it possible when you use html tag, i am not sure about button. You can use with tag like `p:first-letter` and `p:first-line`

Comment: @Sarbaz Is there a `div` container for that button? Something like `<div id="mydiv"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT REQUEST" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"></div>`

Comment: If yes, then can you change the innerHTML of the div? and change it to a button as suggested in the answers?

Comment: @DavidAngulo Yeh, I can give a div for submitting button.

Comment: @Sarbaz Then can you update your question containing the parent element?

Comment: @Sarbaz Does my answer, answers your question?

Comment: @DavidAngulo Thank you, Its also working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the snippet you've given has a parent element with `id` then you can just use the script below.

This will replace the `<input>` with `<button>` then applies the other answers.

```js
document.getElementById('btnDiv').innerHTML = '<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="sub-text">SUBMIT</span> REQUEST</button>';
```

```css
.sub-text{
  font-weight : 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="btnDiv" class="btnDiv"> 
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT REQUEST" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
</div>
```

Or if using jQuery you can use this instead:

```js
$('#btnDiv').html('<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="sub-text">SUBMIT</span> REQUEST</button>');
```

```css
.sub-text{
  font-weight : 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btnDiv" class="btnDiv"> 
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT REQUEST" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into the contact 7 form generator remove the input tag `[submit]`
and append the following

```
<style>
.sub-text{
  font-weight : 700;
}
</style>
<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="sub-text">SUBMIT</span> REQUEST</button>
```

You have a from, as long as you have a input/button type submit it should work the same way it worked with a `[submit]` tag

Comment: @Sarbaz glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

Try using this!

```js
document.getElementById("btnDiv").innerHTML = '<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="sub-text" style="font-weight : 700;">SUBMIT</span> REQUEST</button>';
```

```html
<div id="btnDiv" class="btnDiv"> 
   <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT REQUEST" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try `button tag` instant of `input button`. See below snip.

```css
.sub-text{
  font-weight : 700;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="sub-text">SUBMIT</span> REQUEST</button>
```

Comment: I can't change my HTML.

Comment: @Sarbaz if you can change the css you definitely can change the html as well

Comment: @madalinivascu The HTML is generated by a WordPress plugin. You can only override default CSS generated but not HTML. You can change the HTML in the plugin file but it will be removed during plugin update.

Comment: @Sarbaz You can do whatever you want to do with HTML by jQuery but you have to put lots of effort.

Comment: if i remember correctly contact7 allows for custom submit button