# CSS stylize the second word in select option

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the style for just one word in a select option with CSS ?

```
<select>
  <option class="my-class">Angelina Jolie</option>
  <option class="my-class">Brad Pitt</option>
  <option class="my-class">Robert Duval</option>
  <option class="my-class">James Cameron</option>
</select>
```

Result expected

Angelina **Jolie**
Brad **Pitt**
Robert **Duval**
James **Cameron**

I tried with many selector as *nth-word* but it doesn't work.

Maybe it's just impossible ?

Comment: yes it's just impossible

Comment: You could surround the second word in a `span` and then use a regular css selector like `option.my-class span` to target them.

Comment: @FabianSchöner even that won't work, you can try it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word

Comment: @FabianSchöner that doesn't work for dropdowns

Comment: @TemaniAfif CodeBoyCode ah you guys are right because the select is a native control rendered by the browser, i totally forgot. I'm too used to using plugins to style those.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it, it's impossible. But it's a pity that browsers don't allow to do so.