# Is there a way to select with CSS a string up to a specific character?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to be able to style my `li` list items when converted from markdown without having to tag them.

Specifically:
I want to make bold the first part of a list item when it is formed like a key value pair.

The visual result should look like the equivalent of this:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>key: </strong>value</li>
</ul>
```

So, is there a way to select the string inside the `li` item up to the colon?

Comment: How about showing the HTML you have now, although the real question is, why don't you just put the `strong` element in there?

Comment: if you have actually a list of key-values you could generate instead a description list with dt as the key and dd as the value

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-select-style-first-word

Comment: @Heretic Monkey it's time consuming, I must add ``**text**`` all the time

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in CSS alone, but it is quite straightforward to deploy a snippet of javascript which surrounds the `key:` part of the text with a `<span>`:

`<li><span class="key">key:</span> value</li>`

which then enables you to style that part of the text.

**Working Example:**

```js
const myList = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
const myListItems = myList.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let i = 0; i < myListItems.length; i++) {

  let myListItemColonPosition = myListItems[i].textContent.indexOf(':')

  markup = '';
  markup += '<span class="my-key">';
  markup += myListItems[i].textContent.substring(0, myListItemColonPosition);
  markup += '</span>';
  markup += myListItems[i].textContent.substring(myListItemColonPosition);
  
  myListItems[i].innerHTML = markup;
  
}
```

```css
li {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.my-key {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>key0: value0</li>
<li>key1: value1</li>
<li>key2: value2</li>
<li>key3: value3</li>
<li>key4: value4</li>
</ul>
```