# How can I change the color of a word without using html tags?

Tags: html, css

I want to put the first word(title:) in bold in a text only with css, no html tags

```
<span>title: description</span>
```

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible. Why are you against using HTML tags?

Comment: Similar Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-select-style-first-word

Answer (score -2):

To do so, you must first put the 'title:' inside a different tag like:

```
<span><span style="font-weight: bold;">title:</span> description</span>
```

you can also achieve the same thing in a more popular way in which you define a class and use that class to style the element. you can visit this page for more info:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp