# How to target first letter of p only if it's first child of parent?

Tags: css

for my site with user-generated content, I would like to add drop caps but only if the `p` element is first child of `article` (for example).

I tried various combinations of `first-child` along with `:is` but couldn't get this to work.

For example with this markup:

```
<article>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Text..</p>
</article>
```

I don't want the drop cap to appear, because there is the heading already.

But with this:

```
<article>
    <p>Text.. (this should start with drop cap)</p>
    <p>Text..</p>
</article>
```

I want to have drop cap for the first letter.

Is this possible to do via CSS only?

There's also a case where the first `p` contains just `img` due to Markdown parser, but I guess there is not much I can do about that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the CSS style of first-letter when hover over a parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-select-style-first-word) along with a multitude of similar answers found by searching SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `article p:first-child:first-letter` to target the first letter of the first p-child of every article.

```css
article p:first-child:first-letter {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Text.. (article without heading and dropcap)</p>
  <p>Text..</p>
</article>
<hr/>
<article>
  <h1>Article with heading and without dropcap</h1>
  <p>Text..</p>
  <p>Text..</p>
</article>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter for how those two pseudo-classes work.

Comment: Big facepalm for me.. looks like I misunderstood how `:first-child` really works

Comment: It's often mixed up with how `:first-of-type` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) works, so no worries, it's a common mistake. Most cases i use one of those i have to look it up myself because those cases are very rare for me.