# Highlight wrapped first line in textarea using CSS

Tags: html, css, textarea, word-wrap

I have an textarea element that contains a list of strings. I've written some CSS to highlight the first string (line).

However, this doesn't work well when a long word appears that wraps to a new line:

```css
#example:first-line {
    background-color: #BA2F00; /* BazFoo */
    color: #F00BA2; /* FooBaz */
}
textarea #example {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="example" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">
ThisIsALoooooooooooooooooooooongWord
</textarea>
```

The question is, how do I highlight the entire wrapping first line (i.e. `ThisIsALooo...ongWord`) using CSS?

Comment: Do you have control of the HTML? And/or can you add some Javascript?

Comment: It's not possible with CSS. Because when a word breaks, the browser put the overflow on newlines.

Comment: I do have control of HTML, but cannot add JS.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there's no pseudo attribute for first word... you may have to use Javascript to accomplish this. [CSS to select/style first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-select-style-first-word)
To do this with Javascript, think about the whole text inside the text area as an array of words, and take the index 0, add a span with a style.

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-first-word-of-string

Answer (score -1):

take out the first-line in #example:first-line, just leave it as
#example

oh yah and also add the word-wrap:break-word in the # example, it's easier like that.

Comment: This highlights the whole textarea, not what I meant.

Comment: ooh, i guess u would have to use javascript or jquery