# How to Convert first word of a sentence to UPPERCASE LETTERS in javascript/angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, uppercase, string-conversion

How to Convert first word of a sentence to UPPERCASE LETTERS in javascript/angularjs ?

Comment: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-select-style-first-word

Comment: Have you searched the internet at all for this? Any research?

Comment: yes, I had searched everywhere ..but couldnt find exact solution

Answer (score 0):

let firstUpper = "some text to work".split(' ')[0].toUpperCase();

Comment: Probably you need to join words afterwards into sentence.

Comment: @AvgustinTomsic, agree but this is only for reference

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
 return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
 }

   console.log(capitalizeFirstLetter('foo')); // Foo ´´´
```